# Modal not working in IE9 - on opening developer tools it then works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I've been trying to get a modal working and it seems fine on all tested browsers, except for one problem on IE9. On page load, the modal does not work. If I then open the dev tools  and close them again (or even just keep them open), it works fine. How can I even debug this issue?

Edit: Here's the link: http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="item" data-reveal-id="292">
    <img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg" />
</a>

<div id="292" class="reveal-modal">
    <a href="#" class="close-reveal-modal"><i class="close icon close-reveal-modal"></i></a>
    <div class="header">
    Bow tie neck silk overlay top/dress with sequin hem &#8211; cream, grey                                         <p>&#163;0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://dev.birddartmouth.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/096.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "a.item" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
    var elementClicked = "#" + $(this).attr("data-reveal-id");
    console.log(elementClicked);
    $(elementClicked).foundation('reveal', 'open');
});

$( "a.close-reveal-modal" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
    var openElementClicked = "#" + $(this).parent().attr("id");
    console.log(openElementClicked);
    $(openElementClicked).foundation('reveal', 'close');
});
```

Comment: if (console) console.log else console = {}

Answer (score 2):

console.log throws errors when the console is not open in IE.

Comment out the console lines or check for support

```
window.console && console.log(elementClicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but thought I'd pass on this solution anyway.

To avoid the issue with IE, as @epascarello mentioned, we use a function called `ltc` (log to console) which is sitting in our global.js library.

```
function ltc(what) {
  try {
    console.log(what); 
  } catch(e) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Now instead of using `console.log("my message")`, it's simply `ltc("my message")`;